# Recently my git command line execution time has been very slow

Tags: git

Recently my git command line execution time has been very slow.
The GIt repository is a github enterprise, and detailed trace information for git pull is as follows.

```
06:59:13.583072 exec-cmd.c:243          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin
06:59:13.594065 git.c:463               trace: built-in: git pull
06:59:13.614063 run-command.c:657       trace: run_command: git fetch --update-head-ok
06:59:14.009064 exec-cmd.c:243          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
06:59:14.022066 git.c:463               trace: built-in: git fetch --update-head-ok
06:59:14.051063 run-command.c:657       trace: run_command: GIT_DIR=.git git remote-https origin https://some.github.enterprise/some-repo.git
06:59:14.439062 exec-cmd.c:243          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
06:59:14.444062 git.c:750               trace: exec: git-remote-https origin https://some.github.enterprise/some-repo.git
06:59:14.447067 run-command.c:657       trace: run_command: git-remote-https origin https://some.github.enterprise/some-repo.git
06:59:14.846061 exec-cmd.c:243          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
06:59:15.196064 run-command.c:657       trace: run_command: 'git credential-manager get'
06:59:15.707068 exec-cmd.c:243          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
06:59:15.711066 git.c:750               trace: exec: git-credential-manager get
06:59:15.711066 run-command.c:657       trace: run_command: git-credential-manager get
06:59:16.651067 exec-cmd.c:243          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
06:59:16.655064 git.c:463               trace: built-in: git config --null --list
06:59:22.612580 run-command.c:657       trace: run_command: 'git credential-manager store'
06:59:23.344581 exec-cmd.c:243          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
06:59:23.347581 git.c:750               trace: exec: git-credential-manager store
06:59:23.347581 run-command.c:657       trace: run_command: git-credential-manager store
06:59:24.411583 exec-cmd.c:243          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
06:59:24.417579 git.c:463               trace: built-in: git config --null --list
06:59:35.279580 run-command.c:657       trace: run_command: 'git credential-wincred store'
06:59:35.688606 exec-cmd.c:243          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
06:59:35.692586 git.c:750               trace: exec: git-credential-wincred store
06:59:35.692586 run-command.c:657       trace: run_command: git-credential-wincred store
06:59:39.515582 run-command.c:657       trace: run_command: git rev-list --objects --stdin --not --exclude-hidden=fetch --all --quiet --alternate-refs
06:59:45.133144 run-command.c:1521      run_processes_parallel: preparing to run up to 1 tasks
06:59:45.133144 run-command.c:1549      run_processes_parallel: done
06:59:45.133144 run-command.c:657       trace: run_command: git maintenance run --auto --no-quiet
06:59:45.396143 exec-cmd.c:243          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
06:59:45.402143 git.c:463               trace: built-in: git maintenance run --auto --no-quiet
06:59:49.491234 run-command.c:657       trace: run_command: git merge FETCH_HEAD
06:59:49.751234 exec-cmd.c:243          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
06:59:49.755235 git.c:463               trace: built-in: git merge FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
```

```
> git version
git version 2.44.0.windows.1

> git pull
```

Previously it took several seconds, but now it takes more than 30 seconds.

I tried the `git gc` command but it didn't help. And it is not a problem limited to a specific repository.

Comment: It seems `git config --null --list` takes a long time. How much time does it cost to run the command alone?

Comment: @ElpieKay Thank you for your comment. This command doesn't take long.